# How to filter specific records using a checkbox and display in a subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

When I click the checkbox White, it must only filters out the Race where its W records in the subform here's my code but its not working correctly, any suggestions whats wrong. Thanks in advance

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub White_Click()

strFilter = "Race=W """ & Me.White.OnClick & """"
DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
Forms!Home![Employees subform].Form.Filter = strFilter
Forms!Home![Employees subform].Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement is very confusing:

```
strFilter = "Race=W """ & Me.White.OnClick & """"
```

First of all, there is Race=W.  Then, there's the value of Me.White.OnClick - if that's a checkbox, you'd have a true/false value associate with it but only if you use a value.

Depending on your source table, you probably should do something like this:

```
if me.white.value then
   strFilter = "Race = 'W'"
else
   strFilter = ""
end if
```

I'm not quite sure of the me.white.value - it could be another variable.  Doing it this way will allow for checkbox to be clicked on and off

Comment: Thank you very much really appreciated, ill manage to combine our code and it worked!!!